# Django register.tag take a dynamic variable as kwarg

Tags: django, django-templates

I notice `register.simple_tag` can easily achieve this but I unfortunately can't make the switch right now to use that and would like to use `register.tag` to implement this

have a tag:

```
register.tag(name='foo')
def foo(parser, token):
    bits = token.split_contents()
    # rest of code..
```

template, i have an object that we call `bar` that needs to be passed into `foo`.  Unfortunately i can't seem to get the dynamic value - the below 1. will just be a string 2. will be a string

```
1.
{% foo arg='bar' %}
  {{ foo_* }}
{% endfoo %}
2.
{% foo arg=bar %}
  {{ foo_* }}
{% endfoo %}
```

It looks like I can do

```
{% with b=bar %}
{% foo arg=b %}
  {{ foo_* }}
{% endfoo %}
{% endwith %}
```

I'm hoping to not have to use a `with` statement here and have the "token" come over with the bar object rather than just taking the literal of it.

Comment: You missed the instructions under [Passing template variables](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/custom-template-tags/#passing-template-variables-to-the-tag) - you need to to create a `template.Variable` instance and then call `variable.resolve(context)`.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I see that, but it doesn't take `kwargs` just looks like it takes dynamic `args` - i did see this